# Why does parameter count mismatch?

Tags: qt, qtsql

From what I gather it's a mistake in your database/query and I've tried the following in DB Browser for Sqlite and it works:

```
    UPDATE odgovori SET odgovor="1131" WHERE korisnik_ID="2" AND pitanje_ID="1";
    INSERT INTO odgovori (korisnik_ID, pitanje_ID, odgovor) SELECT "2", "1", "1" WHERE (SELECT Changes()=0);
```

but, when I try this in QT:

```
    Q_ASSERT(qry.driver()->hasFeature(QSqlDriver::NamedPlaceholders));
    qry.prepare("UPDATE odgovori SET odgovor=:odgovor WHERE korisnik_ID=:korisnik_ID AND pitanje_ID=:pitanje_ID;"
    "INSERT INTO odgovori (korisnik_ID, pitanje_ID, odgovor) SELECT :korisnik_ID, :pitanje_ID, :odgovor WHERE (SELECT Changes()=0);");
    qry.bindValue(":odgovor", odgovor);
    qry.bindValue(":korisnik_ID", id);
    qry.bindValue(":pitanje_ID", QString::number(pitanjeid)); 
    qry.exec();
    qDebug()<<qry.lastError();
```

I get `QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")`. I've tried with `?` and `qry.addBindValue` and I get the same result. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you instantiate your `qry` object ?

Comment: @thibsc `QSqlQuery qry;`

Comment: I don't really call two sql commands in one prepare, but I think you should call `bindValue` six times, not three times?

Comment: @wthung calling bindValue six times didn't work either, but I combined your solution with mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by **@wthung** in the comments, I tried manually inserting fixed numbers and the debugger throws `QSqlError("21", "Unable to execute multiple statements at a time", "not an error")`
So I broke the qry into two parts and it worked.

```
qry.prepare("UPDATE odgovori SET odgovor=:odgovor WHERE korisnik_ID=:korisnik_ID AND pitanje_ID=:pitanje_ID;");
qry.bindValue(":odgovor", odgovor);
qry.bindValue(":korisnik_ID", id);
qry.bindValue(":pitanje_ID", QString::number(pitanjeid));
qry.exec();
qry.prepare("INSERT INTO odgovori (korisnik_ID, pitanje_ID, odgovor) SELECT :korisnik_ID, :pitanje_ID, :odgovor WHERE (SELECT Changes()=0);");
qry.bindValue(":odgovor", odgovor);
qry.bindValue(":korisnik_ID", id);
qry.bindValue(":pitanje_ID", QString::number(pitanjeid));
qry.exec();
```